# how can get cookie header data from web page in unity?

Tags: cookies, authentication, unity-game-engine

I have register and login page in unity3d and my website page , when I POST my register or login data from unity3d to my website(magento cms), send to my own error "necessary data rewind wasn't possible" and after see my request in HttpAnalyzer application I find out unity3d cant accept get cookie string . How can get cookie from web after login or register users ?
my unity3d code :

```
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField( "SN", SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier.ToString());
    form.AddField( "UserName ", UserName );
    form.AddField( "year",Year );
    form.AddField( "month", Month );
    form.AddField( "day", Day );
    form.AddField( "dob",Year+"/"+Month+"/"+Day );
    form.AddField( "gender", Gender );
    form.AddField( "password", Pass );
    // Create a download object
    var download = new WWW(URL, form);
    // Wait until the download is done
    yield download;
    // show the Results
    Debug.Log(download.text);   
    if(download.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Err :"+download.error);
        Flag = "1"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you get "necessary data rewind wasn't possible" when the page you try to load make a redirection. I don't think you can make a request in Unity with a "follow redirect" option.

I don't know magenta cms so I can't tell you how to correct this problem.
For your problem of cookie, that's pretty simple in Unity : you just have to intercept the header "SET-COOKIE" from a first call, and then sending back a header with "Cookie" in your next calls :

```
#pragma strict

import System.Collections.Generic;

var url:String = "";
var cookie:String = "";

/// interface
private var stringToEdit:String = "";
function OnGUI(){
    if (url!="" && GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,200,30),"Click"))
        StartCoroutine(LoadData());

    stringToEdit = GUI.TextArea (Rect (10, 50, 600, 400), stringToEdit);
}
/// debug
function Debug(s:String){
    stringToEdit += s+"\n";
}

function LoadData():IEnumerator{
    Debug(url);

    var form : WWWForm = new WWWForm();

    var time:String     = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    form.AddField("time", time);

    // construct your header calls
    var headers : Hashtable = form.headers;
    if(cookie!="")
        headers["Cookie"] = cookie;

    var www : WWW = new WWW(url, form.data, headers);

    yield www;

    if(!www.error){
        Debug(www.text);

        // get the cookie and keep it
        if(www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey('SET-COOKIE')){
            var data:String[] = www.responseHeaders['SET-COOKIE'].Split(";"[0]);
            if(data.length>0){
                cookie = data[0];
            }
        }

    }else
        Debug(www.error);
    // debug
    for(var header:KeyValuePair.<String, String> in www.responseHeaders)
        Debug(header.Key+" "+header.Value);
}
```